# Load different spring configuration when running integrations tests

Tags: spring, maven, configuration, hsqldb, embedded-jetty

I have the following setup: normally my webapp will be deployed on stand-alone server and connect to MySQL database. However I want ability to "self-test" the application with Selenium. So during *mvn clean install* there will be embedded server (Jetty 7), Selenium Server and in-memory database (HSQLDB) that will allow to perform some actions (example user inputs for the webapp).
Now I already setup Selenium/embedded server setup using maven plugins:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Log to the console. -->
                    <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                    <!-- This doesn't do anything for Jetty, but is a workaround for a Maven bug
                        that prevents the requestLog from being set. -->
                    <append>true</append>
                </requestLog>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- 
        *******************************************************
        Start selenium-server before the integration test start
        ******************************************************* 
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-selenium-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>
                            <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                            <multiWindow>true</multiWindow>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-selenium-server</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ********************************************************
        Force to run the testcases in the integration-test phase
        ******************************************************** -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ***********************************************************
        Deploy the war in the embedded jetty of cargo2-maven-plugin
        *********************************************************** -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>jetty7x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                </container>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And it is working just fine. Unfortunately I'm having some issues trying to make Spring/Maven use different XML configuration file when app is being deployed on embedded server for integration testing purposes.

I tried using:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:servlet-context-test.xml" })
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestWebapp extends SeleneseTestCase{
```

(*servlet-context-text.xml* is located in *src/test/resources*)
but when Selenium tests run the webapp is still started with default configuration.

I'm trying to load different xml file because I basically want to use this:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
   <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/schema.sql"/>
   <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/fk.sql"/>
   <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

instead of my normal dataSource declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Spring profiles (http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/). With a profile, you can activate/deactivate beans in different ways (programamtically, with environment variable etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful to someone out there. I finally resolved this issue using Maven profiles (separate profiles for integration testing and for production build) and filtering (parametrized my servlet-context.xml in regards to importing either dataSource.xml or dataSourceIntegrationTesting.xml). Works like a charm.